# R- Adding a date column to a dataframe based on part of filename

Tags: r, date, dataframe, filenames

A bit specific question from a R beginner (I already searched and didn't find a solution).

I have a bunch of csv files with an ugly column date named "W-01", "Th-02", "F-0" for Wednesday-1st, Thusrsday-2nd, Friday-03th and so on. The rest of the values are numeric format, already classified with colClasses in the code:

> W  01;37.91;33.00;31.00;27.09;27.09;31.00;33.60;
>   Th 02;40.00;37.19;35.69;35.01;35.01;35.94;40.00;
>   F  03;43.04;41.19;40.77;40.92;40.69;40.92;41.93;

Each file is generated every month, with the following pattern:

For august for example: prmdiari_20160801_20160831

I would like to use the date embedded in the file name to add a column to each dataframe with a practical date format (%D, %M, %Y).

Here part of the code where I'm already cleaning the data and melting to a long format dataframe. I was thinking using the function for reading each csv to store the file name, extract the date pattern (for example "20160801_20160831") and add a date column based on the initial and final data for each file, but don't know how to handle it without implementing a for loop (not the best solution).

```
# Creating the list files

prmdiari.list <- list.files(pattern = "prmdiari*", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

# Reading each file and appending the rows to a unique dataframe

prmdiari <- do.call("rbind",lapply(prmdiari.list, FUN = function(files) 

  {read.csv2(files, header=FALSE, sep=";", dec = ".", skip = 2, colClasses = c("character", rep("numeric", 25), "NULL"))}))

# Naming the output dataframe columns

colnames(prmdiari) <- c("day", "H01", "H02", "H03", "H04", "H05", "H06", "H07", "H08", "H09", "H10", "H11", "H12", "H13", "H14", "H15", "H16", "H17", "H18", "H19", "H20", "H21", "H22", "H23", "H24", "H25" )

# Removing the asterisk rows

prmdiari.clean <- subset(prmdiari, !prmdiari$day == "*")

# Transforming the dataframe from wide to long format

prmdiari.longformat <- melt(prmdiari.clean, id.vars = "day", variable.name = "Period", value.name = "Market value")
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Look at the grep function family and strsplit for preprocessing and, strptime for datetime parsing, be carefull when storing times in data.frames, use POSIXct format, not POSIXlt.

Comment: `fname <- "prmdiari_20160801_20160831";
F <- strsplit(fname, '_')[[1]];
as.Date(F[2], "%Y%m%d")`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to do it with lapply function